# How to convert 1,4 pentadiene to 1,3 pentadiene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Are there any 'conjugating agents' to accomplish the above transformation? If not, then how to proceed?

Comment: Deprotonation with nBuLi then quenching of the anion at -75 will produce a mixture that is majority the conjugated diene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinctive answer would be to use a precious metal catalyst. Palladium usually displays this sort of activity. However, this article should cover most methods from basic and metallic to photochemical. 
https://www.thieme-connect.de/media/10.1055-b-003-125756/lookinside/10-1055-b-003-125756_chapter012-1.jpg